# nodejs objects property can only be changed to int and not string

Tags: javascript, node.js

i just got this wierd issue in  which the code below returns the refno for all Object in the array as expected **But**

```
let records = await Expense.find({}).exec();      // records is an array of objects [{},{}]
  for (let obj of records) {                   // the obj has a refno property which i want to change
    obj.refno = 0                             // this works as expected by changing refno property to 0
  }
console.log(records)
```

**this code of code below** of chaning the properties value to string **Does not work**

```
 for (let obj of records) {
    obj.refno = "QM"+obj.refno
  }
console.log(records)                       // IN this the refno. doesnt change
```

my requirment is to change the refno to a string

```
//the object
{
 _id: 5efed2c813b03d331e4dc052,
    refno: 102,
    project: 'EV Battery Pack',
    invoiceno: 'dia',
    description: 'black frame',
    date: '2020-07-03',
}
```

so chaning the property to other number works but not to string , i cant get how this happens or am i missing something ?, anyways i got around this by declaring another property and storing the string in it but I dont know why the int cant be changed to string inside object

can some one explain why this happens
thanks for help

Edit : schema of expense

```
var schema = new Schema({
  refno: { type: Number, require: true },
  project: { type: String, require: true },
  projectid: { type: Number, require: true },
  invoiceno: { type: String, require: true },
  description: { type: String, require: true },
  date: { type: String, require: true },
  INR: { type: Number, require: true },
  USD: { type: Number, require: true },
  remarks: { type: String, require: true },
});
```

Comment: Is it a mongoQuery?

Comment: could you show us your schema of Expense

Comment: yes using mongoose to retrive the array of objects

Comment: you could try `.lean()` like this `let records = await Expense.find({}).lean().exec();`

Comment: The refno is a number in the schema and i added the schema in the post , Thanks :D

Comment: @Ifaruki Omg Thaks It works , Just got to know that Queries returns Mongoose document class used to think its just objects

Comment: yea i had this problem too. had a depressiv time there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your `.find().exec()` call  are *mongoose documents* which do not allow to modify their values if the resulting datatype is not compliant with the schema-constraints.

However, you can use `.lean()` (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on the mongoose document which will convert it to a plain js-object which you then can modify arbitrarily:

```
let records = await Expense.find({}).exec().lean();
```